# Display UIView below navigation bar in Swift programattically

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a webview that would like to fill up the whole screen only start ***below the Navigation bar*** so that the top is visible. By that I don't mean that the view is behind the navigation bar. I mean in the Y-coordinate, its top begins at the bottom of the navigation bar.

I can get it fill up the screen, however, the top is currently covered by the navigation bar, clipping off the top.

Right now, I am simply trying to move it down 64 points, the size of the status bar and navigation bar, but my code is crashing when I try to create a frame with a bad instruction error.

Here is my code:

```
 let webVew = wkWebView()
    
     override func loadView() {
            
            self.view = webView
        }
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            let frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40)) as! CGRect  
//CRASHES on above line with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
            
           webView.frame = frame
        }
```

How can I get the top of the webview to start at the bottom of the Navigation bar

Comment: use constraints top,bottom,trailing,leading

Comment: I'd like to do this entirely progamatically. Are you suggestiong creating constraints in code?

Comment: It turns out this can be set with self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []. There are also similar settings in storyboard